# Using C++ template function with Generator type

Tags: c++, templates, generator

I'm implementing a template function which sets the values of the first n elements of a sequence pointed to by a parameter iterator to values returned by calls to a generator function.

I have the following code:

```
template <typename IteratorOut, typename SizeType, typename Generator> IteratorOut createSequence(IteratorOut out, SizeType n, Generator gen) {
    std::vector<Generator> vec;
    for (SizeType i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        vec.push_back(gen());
    }
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), out);

    return out;
}
```

I'm testing the function with the following:

```
int generate () {
    return 5;
}
...
std::vector<int> vec_int;

createSequence(vec_int.begin(), 5, generate);
for (std::vector<int>::iterator iter = vec_int.begin(); iter != vec_int.end(); iter++) {
    std::cout << *iter << std::endl;
}
```

I get "error: invalid conversion from ‘int (*)()’ to ‘int’". Can you see what's wrong with my template function?

Comment: Are you sure about your error message? I get it the other way round: "error: invalid conversion from ‘int' to ‘int (*)()’". Btw, which compiler are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of the vector is wrong:

```
std::vector<Generator> vec;
```

Here, `Generator` is a function, and you want a vector of `int`s instead:

```
std::vector<SizeType> vec; // SizeType is an euphemism for int
```

But maybe you don't need a vector at all!

```
for (SizeType i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    *out = gen(); // is this what you want?
    ++out;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted, I had misunderstood the Generator-type. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well, `Generator` is the type of the generator function, not the type returned by the generator function. And you are creating a vector of such type. Hence the error, when you insert into the array you are trying to convert a `int` returned by the `Generator` into a `int(*)()`.

But why don't you just insert into the secuence directly, instead of going through the vector?

```
template <typename IteratorOut, typename SizeType, typename Generator> 
IteratorOut createSequence(IteratorOut out, SizeType n, Generator gen) {
    for (SizeType i = 0; i < n; i++)
       *out++ = gen();
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted, I had misunderstood the Generator-type. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, that algorithm already exists in the standard library. Don’t use a temporary vector, but don’t use a loop either. Use [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n):

```
template <typename IteratorOut, typename SizeType, typename Generator>
IteratorOut createSequence(IteratorOut out, SizeType n, Generator gen) {
    std::generate_n(out, n, gen);
    return out;
}
```

And in C++11 in fact, this can be rewritten as:

```
template <typename IteratorOut, typename SizeType, typename Generator>
IteratorOut createSequence(IteratorOut out, SizeType n, Generator gen) {
    return std::generate_n(out, n, gen);
}
```

… in other words, your function is just another name for `std::generate_n`. The signature and semantics are identical.